# Laravel 9 require laravel/ui to use Auth::routes

Tags: php, laravel-9

I am upgrading my project to Laravel 9. However, when I tried to run `php artisan`, I got an error message.

> In Auth.php line 60: To use the Auth::routes() method, please install
> the laravel/ui package.

So I install the package, but I still get the same error message.
What might be the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 11):

Step 1: (Install Laravel UI)

`composer require laravel/ui`

Step 2: (Generate Auth UI)

`php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`

Also please read the documentation:
https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/README.md

Comment: whenever I run any php artisan command, I always get that error message, so I can not execute step 2

Comment: i added cd [your-project-name]
and then composer require laravel/ui
and it worked @AryabhimaA.Rahman

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue but had it working locally but not on the web host. In case you are uploading to a remote server and you can't run composer/artisan make sure to also upload the files in `bootstrap/cache` (packages.php and services.php)

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that you need to install the `Laravel/ui` package in order to use the `Auth::routes()` method.

To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

**Step 1:** Install the `laravel/ui` package using `Composer`:

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

**Step 2:** Generate authentication scaffolding for it.

For Bootstrap-based scaffolding:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

For Vue.js-based scaffolding:

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

For React-based scaffolding:

```
php artisan ui react --auth
```

**Step 3:** Use `Auth::routes()` in routes/web.php

```
// routes/web.php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// ...

Auth::routes();

// ...
```