# Deploying Laravel to Heroku and getting Auth Routes Error

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, heroku

I've deployed a Laravel app to Heroku with Laravel's built in authentication. Heroku is returning this error:

**In order to use the Auth::routes() method, please install the laravel/ui package.**

However, in the heroku console I've run composer require laravel/ui.

I also have "laravel/ui": "^4.2" in my composer.json.

I'm running Laravel 10.7.1.

Any recommendations or help on what I'm doing wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537344/laravel-9-require-laravel-ui-to-use-authroutes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 9 require laravel/ui to use Auth::routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537344/laravel-9-require-laravel-ui-to-use-authroutes)

Comment: Try updating composer.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that and it still shows the same error

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue. I had added this to my `composer.json`

```
"post-install-cmd": {
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "chmod -R 777 public/"
}
```

Once I removed this it worked.